# Visual Studio Shell (Isolated Mode) Redistributables

Tags: visual-studio, vsx

I want to use the Isolated Shell as a front-end for a custom debugger.

If I understand correctly, the Visual Studio Debug Package implements the 'User Interface Parts' of the Visual Studio Debugger system, that is, among other things, all the debugger windows (stack, watch, breakpoints etc).

Is the VS Debug Package a part of the Isolated Mode redistributable? In other words, can I reuse the existing Visual Studio debug-related windows in my Isolated Shell application?

SIS

Answer (score 2):

Some of the windows may be disabled in the default config options in the template, but the debug-related windows are available.

Comment: You just need to enable the full debugger in the main stub VSCT file.
At the end of the file, uncomment the lines that include all the debugger commands.